# 1 checkbox with 2 value from sql pass the selection

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

Hi all 
Now is 2 week that i searching for an answer to my problem and no luck. hope somone can help me on this

i have a chackbox option that i call from the database

```
<form style="margin-top:-30px" method="POST" action="extradata.php">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT ext_id,ext_price,ext_name,ext_description FROM tbl_extra ORDER by ext_id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
while ($number > $i) {
$NA= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_name");
$PR= mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_price");

print "<input type='checkbox' name='extra[]' value='$NA'></td>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

What i trying to do is to pass the value to `extradata.php` with 2 value
1.`$NA`,
2.`$PR`
when selected box then insert to the database the value of `$NA` to `ex_tra` and `$PR` to `ex_price`

the `extradata.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'library/config.php';

$id=$_POST['pd_id'];
$ssid=$_POST['ct_session_id'];
$total=$_POST['tot'];
$name=$_POST['basedes'];
$qty=$_POST['ct_qty'];
$extra_array = $_POST['extra'];
if ( $extra_array > "0" ) {
foreach ($extra_array as $one_extra) {
$source .= $one_extra.", "; }
$extra = substr($source, 0, -2);
} else {}
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_cart (pd_id, ct_qty, ct_session_id, ex_tra, ex_tra2, ex_price, ct_date) VALUES ('$id','$qty','$ssid','$extra','$name','$total', NOW())");

?>
```

Best regard to all

Comment: Any chance you looked at the preview when submitting your question?

Answer (score 2):

Sending two values in one variable is bound to get messy. I would just send the id and get the corresponding values from the database again in `extradata.php`.

If you really want to send multiple values, I would use fixed indices for the checkboxes (not `extra[]` but `extra[SOME_NUMBER]` and add a hidden field next to it (`extra_pr[SOME_NUMBER]`?) to pass the second value.

Note that you have to use fixed indices as unchecked checkboxes don´t get posted but all hidden fields will get posted.

Comment: Thank you finaly i found a solution print "<input style='width: 30px; height: 15px;' type='checkbox' onClick='ReadForm (this.form, false);' name='extra[]' value='$NA +$PR ₪'></td>"; that give me all the value include the total price then i use in extradata.php $vowels = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "₪", "+", ".");
$string = str_replace($vowels, '', $extra); to remove the price and vwala i get one table with the product names and one with the price

Comment: @gabby That's a solution, but like I said, that is bound to get messy, in this case when a name contains numbers.